# Transfer fieldgroups through features

Tags: features, entities

I need transfer fieldgroup through features, but always when I add field group into feature I see status "overriden". How I can add fieldgroup into features correctly?
This fieldgroup added for taxonomy vocabulary.

This problem described in this topic http://drupal.org/node/1619154 but it not works for me :(

I use Drupal 7.14, field_group 7.x-1.1, features 7.x-1.0, CTools 7.x-1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem - features is not paste this line include_once('my_feature.features.inc'); into my_feature.module